# How to pull css attributes from

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to pull attributes from CSS to be used in Javascript.  I've googled what I'm looking for so many times and in so many ways my fingers are about to fall off.

I'm looking to change font size to three different font sizes: 15px, 28px, and 40px.  This would be toggled using three buttons.  However, when you choose a font size, some of the other CSS attributes need to change in order to resize the text and padding to align with the element "behind" it, so that it doesn't push off the side and look ugly.  I'm planning on doing the resizing automatically with Javascript, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to pull the "text size in pixels" attribute from the page in order to apply an "if/else" argument.  This would need to be done in browser and I've found a .getComputedStyle command.  But as I can't get it to work I'm not sure if that's what I need or not.

```
<body>

    <p id="spaz">Text to be resized.</p>

    <button type="button" onclick="txtszl()">large</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="txtszm()">medium</button>

    <script>
        function txtszl(){
            document.getElementById("spaz").style.fontSize="40px";
        }
        function txtszm(){
            document.getElementById("spaz").style.fontSize="28px";
        }
        var $txtelement = document.getElementById("spaz");
        var $txtsize = $txtelement.getComputedStyle("fontSize");

        if ($txtsize == 40px){
            alert("It's forty!");
        }else{
            alert("Nope!");
        }

    </script>

</body>
```

That's what I have come up with.  Any help/links would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wrathchild77/6LJaM/

```
function txtszl() {
         document.getElementById("spaz").style.fontSize = "40px";
         check();
     }

     function txtszm() {
         document.getElementById("spaz").style.fontSize = "28px";
         check();
     }

     function check() {
         var $txtsize = document.getElementById("spaz").style.fontSize;

         if ($txtsize == "40px") {
             alert("It's forty!");
         } else {
             alert("Nope!");
         }
     }
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The `style` element refers to the inline styling and will not return a value; it is used for *setting* a style, not retrieving it. `getComputedStyle()` is used for retrieving style values.

Comment: @AstroCB Well, it would return a value if the style was set inlined, but it doesn't take in account inherited styles or external styles.

Comment: I have this one working like a charm!  I'd give you an up vote but I'm not reputable enough at the moment.  Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: No problem, you should be able to mark it as the answer if it worked for you even if you don't have the reputation to up vote yet.

Comment: @swestfall It works because you're already using it to set the size. It doesn't take into account inherited or external styles, so it won't work if the OP changes the CSS for the element *anywhere* else. It's safer to use `getComputedStyle()`.

Comment: I agree with what you are saying but in his question he is using jquery to inject an inline style. Here is a fiddle using the computed style method. http://jsfiddle.net/wrathchild77/6LJaM/2/

Comment: @swestfall Are the Alerts working on your jsfiddle.  They don't seem to be doing anything on my end.

Comment: @swestfall Alrighty,  thanks for the demo on how to use .getComputedStyle.  I'll look into both of these methods a little further.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) function returns a [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration).

```
var txtElementStyles = getComputedStyle($txtelement, null),
    fontSize = txtElementStyles.getPropertyValue('font-size');
```